# How to include an exception in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to bold everything in a string that comes before a `:` and do it the following way (PHP):

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.*):/', '<span class="bold">\\1:</span>', $string);
```

Now I need an exception: I do NOT want to bold the text if there is a `(` before the `:`. Is this possible?

(So basically `Size: 123` should get bolded, but `We increase this (Max: 30)` should NOT get bolded)

Comment: `<img alt="Foo:bar" />` Now what? // Even better: `<a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/image.png"/></a>` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use :

```
$string = preg_replace('/([^(]*):/', '<span class="bold">\\1:</span>', $string);
```

It will match any character before the : except (.

Comment: That's great, thank you. If I would now want to NOT bold the `Max:` from the original example at all, how would I do that (since currently "Max:" gets bolded)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to break ... lets say: Everything

```
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="http://example.com/image.png"/></a>
```

Now what?

I assume, that this `Size: 123` is not "somewhere" on the page. So format it, when you *output* it

```
list($name, $value) = array_map('trim', explode(':', $attribute));
echo "<span class=\"bold\">$name</span>: $value";
```

It would also be better to have this as array in the first place like in `array('Size'=>'123')`

Comment: Nothing is going to break, html is not allowed in that place. Also this is used for outputting only, not for storing.
The data is stored properly, for this kind of text I can't have a structure like "size -> 30" because the attributes are different for each dataset.

Comment: @user2015253 That doesn't explain, why you can't use arrays instead of plain-text strings (`array('fooName' => 'barValue')`)

Answer (score 0):

@blue112 is almost there but in order not do bold `Max` in the string `We increase this (Max: 30)` one needs to make sure that the *whole* string doesn't contain any opening brackets. This is done by adding the beginning-of-string marker `^`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^([^(]*):/', '<span class="bold">\\1:</span>', $string);
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?33rr6).